# Citing Tweet with BibLaTeX/Biber and apa7 class

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa7

I'm writing a student research paper with the `apa7` class and I'd like to cite some tweets. However, this isn't as easy as it sounds as APA has specific guidelines to formatting tweets — plain `@online` won't work. How can I get these Tweets to appear in my bibliography correctly? I don't mind adding fields in manually as I only have three Tweets that I need to cite. Here's how it's supposed to look:

[image: APA Tweet formatting]

Answer (score 3):

there is an example bib in the biblatex-apa documentation. It contains also tweets

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-apa-test-references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{10.15:103a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

The entry is formatted like this:

```
@ONLINE{10.15:103a,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE            = {Tweet},
  GROUPAUTHOR             = {{APA Education}},
  GROUPAUTHOR+an:username = {1="@APAEducation"},
  TITLE                   = {College Students are Forming Mental-Health
                             Clubs--and They're Making a Difference @washingtonpost},
  TITLEADDON              = {Thumbnail with link attached},
  EPRINT                  = {Twitter},
  DATE                    = {2018-06-29},
  URL                     = {https://twitter.com/apaeducation/status/1012810490530140161}
}
```

Comment: where is that document located? I read the "APA BibLaTeX style
Citation and References macros for BibLaTeX" (from CTAN) and couldn't find it.I thought I would need to learn how to edit .bst files but your solution is great. Thank you!

Comment: @RyanKnutson You can find the example `.bib` file for example at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib (I'd have thought the file would be installed into `<tex install root>/doc/latex/biblatex-apa`, but at least in MikTeX that does not seem to be the case).

Comment: the bib was mentioned in the biblatex-apa documentation and then I simply checked on ctan https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa